# What is the lowest level open/public API through which Linux graphics system talks to the GPU?

Tags: linux, opengl, user-interface, gpu, x11

I've got the idea that in old days, XFree86 used /dev/fb* framebuffer devices. But now looks like the GUI system uses OpenGL, which is an open standard. So is OpenGL the lowest level open API? By 'open', I mean no obscure private ioctl or closed-source stuff.

**Update:**

I've got what I need after discussions with @datenwolf, who also provides a great answers. 
In case anyone wants more coding detail: The X server driver is the lowest common level for the X system on top of any GPUs. To know what kind of interface an X server driver must implement: refer to [DDX Design](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-server/ddxDesign.html), it is a detailed doc for the latest X.org that tells you how to write an X driver.

Comment: X is still the same as ever was, OpenGL is just a piece on top merely used for some new effects and to piss off the user and burn more computing power ( because under linux you have the luxury to do so considering the quality of the GPU drivers ... ).

Comment: @user2485710 hmm.. so X still uses framebuffer devices? But I can't find any /dev/fb* in my Linux box with a fancy NVIDIA GPU. There is "framebuffer" concept in OpenGL too, but I am pretty sure it is not the "framebuffer" previous X used.

Comment: the kernel takes care of both the fb and your drivers, X doesn't really care about that, it just manages your windows and your inputs.

Comment: @user2485710 then through what API or at least an ioctl standard X talks to the driver for drawing on the screen? Using framebuffer it is simple, just mmap a /dev/fd* then manipulate the memory, but now framebuffer doesn't necessarily exist.

Comment: yes but the point is when you deal with fb you basically deal with the kernel, if you want to deal with X/X11 from a programmer viewpoint, you have only 1 option: Xlib .

Comment: I may fail to make the question clear. But Xlib is open-sourced, so there is a lower level open API or standard that Xlib uses to draw stuff, and there might be another level of open API under which Xlibs uses, and so on. I understand GPU drivers are in kernel, talking to drivers means talking to the kernel, etc. But as far as I know, some GPU, such as NVIDIA, has the userspace libs, which X must talk to either directly or indirectly, close-source/close API. So my question is, where is the last open layer in the Linux graphics stack?

Comment: @W.Sun: You have a misconception of how the X server works. The X server by itself does not talk to graphics hardware. Instead the X server loads driver modules which do the talking and those talk to the hardware in which way they see fit. Some drivers do all the low level work. Others rely on kernel services. the /dev/fbdev is just one way to access the graphics memory, but it's not the only way to go and no high performance driver actually touches it.

Comment: @W.Sun: For open source drivers there is the DRM interface provided by the kernel, but proprietary drivers don't use it. Instead the fit the kernel with a custom module, through which they talk. **There is no definitive standard API!**

Comment: @W.Sun: Also `Xlib` does no graphics business at all. All it does is communicating with the X display server.

Comment: @datenwolf  i noticed there was "xwindow" is the title. Maybe that is why people here keep mentioning X. I edited the title to avoid X.  I think I've for the answer.

Comment: @W.Sun: What can I tell you: There is no "graphics" API in the Linux kernel. It doesn't deal in this business. All graphics drivers live in the user space (even with Wayland). DRM and the proprietary modules are just conduits through which you can directly talk with the graphics card. The lowest level graphics system you actually have in current Linux systems is X. Wayland itself is just a framebuffer surface flinger and actually doesn't deal with GPUs; it's just a protocol. And so far Wayland only works with DRI/DRM based graphics drivers provided by the Mesa project (also doing X drivers).

Comment: @W.Sun: The /dev/fbdev you find on some Linux systems is just a glorified mapping of framebuffer memory to a character device. You write data to it, and it ends up in the memory space of the graphics card. There's no hardware acceleration involved and it's totally dumb. In addition the kernel knows to tell the graphics hardware to switch video resolutions, but that's it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Linux there is no "lowest level API" exposed by the kernel that does graphics operations. All graphics drivers are actually implemented in the user space by so called "state trackers", which use special kernel functions to talk directly with the graphics hardware¹. The open source drivers implemented as part of the Mesa project use the Linux specific DRM API to talk to the hardware. The proprietary drivers from NVidia and AMD each use their very specific kernel module instead.

Now when it comes to end program usability Mesa and the proprietary drivers differ a bit:

NVidia's and AMD/ATI's proprietary drivers offer no API at all to end user programs to use for. Instead they're implemented as modules to load by the X server; the X server expects the driver modules to follow a specific scheme, which usually changes with major changes in the X server, so each X server major version bump usually required to update the driver modules as well.

The X server in turn provides a well known command stream based graphics API. Graphics commands sent over this API are scheduled by the X server and dispatched into called to the right functions of the driver module. The driver module in turn contains the whole intelligence for talking with the GPU and turns the commands coming from the X server into commands toward the GPU.

So to speak the X server is the lowest level universal graphics API currently available to Linux programs (except for programs that would go the length to implement everything to use the X driver modules directly).

When it comes to X11, the drivers that are part of the Mesa project are no different than the proprietary drivers. However because Mesa is open source its developers began implementing ways that programs could use Mesa and its drivers directly without having talk to it through the X server. For that they choose to expose an API conformant with the EGL specification. Unfortunately EGL is rather useless on its own because it requires an external display system to be present (or you can do only off-screen rendering).

This is where Wayland enters the picture. Wayland *is not* a display system. It is however a protocol that allows the building blocks of a display system to talk with each other. One central component of a Wayland based display system is the *compositor* which actually takes hold of the so called "seat" (= display device and associated input devices). Programs that want to display something on the screen use Wayland to open a connection with the compositor, which gives them a display to use EGL on. That they then can use to create actual drawing surfaces to do their graphics on.

---

[1]: Actually for some drivers (of legacy hardware) the X server must be started with root privileges, so that it can use the special function `ioperm(…)` to gain direct access to the hardware using the `out*(…)` and `in*(…)` functions and open `/dev/mem` for memory access. In this case there is *zero* support by the kernel regarding the communication with the graphics hardware. But for security and performance reasons nobody does (program) that anymore.

Answer (score 3):

[DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager) and [KMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_setting#Linux), at least for the open-source driver stacks.

Comment: with a small side note: DRM works if the driver work

Comment: @genpfault Sorry I still not quite understand. What do you mean by "for the open-source driver stack"? If I have a NVIDIA card using their private driver, what's the lowest level open API then?

Comment: @W.Sun: None. The NVidia driver is the driver and does all the heavy lifting. In fact the NVidia driver is providing the lowest level API to the rest of the graphics stack. If you want to get technical there's a proprietary kernel module that opens a channel to the GPU and the NVidia X driver module implements all the actual talking to the GPU.

Comment: OK, I've got it. Two approaches: DRM (through libdrm), KMS (libkms in libdrm); or OpenGL (glx, especially for proprietary NVIDIA driver. EGL in Wayland).

Comment: @W.Sun: **NO!!!*** The X Server does not use OpenGL! The X server **is** the lowest level when it comes to NVidia proprietary drivers. There's no level beneath it in that case. It loads the `nvidia' driver module and that talks more or less directly to the hardware, through a small channel, created by a custom kernel module. There is no further API inbetween.

Comment: @W.Sun: In principle you could assume the API that the X server expects the driver modules to expose as the lowest level. So in theory you actually *could* load the NVidia X driver module into your own program. But to work, that program would have to implement a complete X server, because that driver module API is highly X specific.

Comment: @datenwolf. See my comment to the question.

Comment: @datenwolf. The what is the " driver module API" called? It must have a name I guess.

Comment: @W.Sun: "X device driver interface". There's no official name for it, because it's just part of X and the actual API changes with every major version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44660/discussion-between-w-sun-and-datenwolf)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your own GPU-accelerated renderer, or use `GLX`

- The lowest level access to the GPU is via **X** renderering backends.
- The lowest level backend available to **X** is `GLX`.
- `GLX` renders **X** directly to the GPU-accelerated *OpenGL pipeline*.
- The default framebuffered `xrender` backend is unaccelerated.

[**Compton**](https://github.com/chjj/compton) is an opensource compositor for **X** that uses the `GLX` backend.

- It is a good example of using *OpenGL* to accelerate **X**.
- `GLX` should be getting bindings for *Vulkan*, providing multiple *OpenGL pipelines*.
- `GLX` only accelerates **X** in 2D, because **X** is a 2D app.
- For 3D apps, a [**custom renderer**](https://unity3d.com) is required.

Answer (score -1):

The [DRM](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/gpu/introduction.html) GPU driver.
is the open...